# UIImageView and autolayout

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a view that is set up nicely using autolayout. The view contains a series of labels stacked from top to bottom. I am allowing the intrinsic size of these labels to determine the size of the view.

The final step is to add a background from an image. I started by trying the `colorWithPatternImage` method on `UIColor` but this isn't quite what I am looking for. I do not want to tile the image, and I can not guarantee it will always be larger than the intrinsic size of the view.

Similarly, adding a `uiImageView` to the view itself doesn't quite work. The view will expand to accommodate the image when I want to keep the intrinsic size based on the labels.

I guess what I am looking for is the following.

1) The background should have no effect on the size of the view.
2) The image should be scaled to fill the view but in it's original aspect ration (so cropping edges if necessary).

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I needed it for a `UIImageView` inside a dynamically-sized view in a `UITableViewCell`, but the image refused to shrink below its instristic size and instead worked as a minimum-size constraint for the superview. The only way I could get it ignore the intristic size is by lowering the priority at which it is enforced, right after creating the cell:

`[imageView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
   forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[imageView setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
   forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];`

After this, all my constraints magically started working. In the OP's case, setting `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` is also required, as per Mundi's answer.

Comment: setting xib content Compression Resistance & content Hugging  for UIImageViiew to 249 (249 < 250) resolved problem

Comment: for uitalbeviewcell place all element to single view -> view to contentView

Comment: I used the same solution on a Today widget with dynamic height. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, add a `UIImageView` as the first subview to the view. Make sure its size always matches the view.

Then, in Interface Builder or code, set the `contentMode`:

```
backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Comment: Thanks - but how do I make sure the size matches using constraints (I am not using IB)? If I set a constraint such that the size == the view, the view just expands to meet that constraint (instead of the image shrinking). I can't hardcode a fixed height for the view unfortunately, since the size is content-dependent.

Comment: You can override `layoutSubviews` and make sure the background image view is the same size.

Comment: I think we should call `layoutIfNeeded`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach this. Hopefully it helps. :)

```
CGRect        contentFrame     = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 0);      //  This will be the frame used to create the background image view.
UIEdgeInsets  contentInsets    = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20);      //  The margins by which the labels will be inset from the edge of their parent view.
CGFloat       labelHeight      = 21;
CGFloat       verticalGap      = 8;                        //  The vertical space between labels
CGFloat       y                = contentInsets.top;
int           numberOfLabels   = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLabels; i++) {

    CGRect   frame  = CGRectMake(contentInsets.left, y, self.view.frame.size.width - (contentInsets.left + contentInsets.right), labelHeight);
    UILabel *label  = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: frame] autorelease];

    //  customize the label here

    [self.view addSubview: label];
    contentFrame = CGRectUnion(contentFrame, label.frame);

    y += labelHeight + verticalGap;
}

contentFrame.size.height += contentInsets.bottom;

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: contentFrame] autorelease];
[backgroundImageView setClipsToBounds: YES];
[backgroundImageView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[backgroundImageView setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"background_image.png"]];
[self.view insertSubview: backgroundImageView atIndex: 0];
```

Comment: I am trying to use autolayout exclusively. Maybe I can apply the same logic though.